# UILabel to render partial character using clip

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I want a UILabel to render a partial character by setting the lineBreakMode to clip. But it is clipping the entire character. Is there a different way to clip a word so that only partial character is displayed?

Lets say I have a string like:

"Hello Word" and that string is in a myLabel with a width that only fits the 5 characters and part of the "W" I want it still to render part of the "W" and not drop it from the render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you'd have to render the string into an image and clip that.